# Creating an extension file

Tags: ios, xcode

First of all, pardon me for asking a simple question. If I have a file called `MyViewController.swift` and I want to make another file say MyDetails as an extension to MyViewController so that the new file will be called `MyViewController+MyDetails.swift`. How can I create such a file in Xcode?

Should I directly create a new swift file and name it  `MyViewController+MyDetails` or is there another approach by which I can create a file called MyDetails from MyViewController so that the new file generated would automatically appear as `MyViewController+MyDetails.swift`?

Comment: Unlike Java, file names do not matter in Swift. You just create a new file and call if whatever you want

Comment: You can just create a file (Top menu > New > File > Swift File) and see what happens. Try it! If you get any errors you can't solve - then you can come and ask specific questions about them.